WPF Binding the datetime relative to the current time
I am looking for a way to bind a datetime but display the difference with the current time.
Here is the C# code:
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{ 

    public ObservableCollection<Information> Informations;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Informations = new ObservableCollection<Information>
        {
            new Information() { When = DateTime.Now, What = "A first information" },
            new Information() { When = DateTime.Now, What = "Another information" },
            new Information() { When = DateTime.Now, What = "An other information" }
        };

       ltvInfos.ItemsSource = Informations;

    }
}


public class Information : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] String propertyName = "")
    {
        var handler = PropertyChanged;
        handler?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }


    public string What
    {
        get { return what; }
        set { what = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private string what;


    public DateTime When
    {
        get { return when; }
        set { when = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
    }
    private DateTime when;

}

And the WPF:
 <ListView x:Name="ltvInfos">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                
           <DataTemplate>
                <WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding When}" Margin="5,0"/>
                     <TextBlock Text="{Binding What}" />
                </WrapPanel>
           </DataTemplate>
                
      </ListView.ItemTemplate>
 </ListView>`

Here is the result:

And what I am looking for is to display something like that:

I didn't find any way to do it except running a timer that update another property every second to calculate the difference with the current time.

It is one of straightforward ways. Why don't you implement it?

@emoacht because it looks heavy to update each second my collection of Informations that will contains thousands of objects. If there is a way to just "translate" that with a sort of binding, it will be far more optimal!

If you are keen to save resources (whether you really need to do is another story), you can 1) Place the timer logic in view to avoid being updated on each tick from view model, 2) Share a timer among instances, 3) Employ virtualization.
Let's say, create a custom TextBlock which has a timer as a static member and share it among the instances.
public class TimerTextBlock : TextBlock
{
    private static DispatcherTimer _timer;

    static TimerTextBlock()
    {
        _timer = new() { Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1) };
        _timer.Start();
    }

    public DateTime Time
    {
        get { return (DateTime)GetValue(TimeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(TimeProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty TimeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Time",
            typeof(DateTime),
            typeof(TimerTextBlock),
            new PropertyMetadata(default(DateTime), OnTimeChanged));

    private static void OnTimeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        ((TimerTextBlock)d).IsRunning = ((DateTime)e.NewValue != default);
    }

    private bool _isRunning;
    public bool IsRunning
    {
        get => _isRunning;
        set
        {
            if (_isRunning != value)
            {
                _isRunning = value;
                if (_isRunning)
                {
                    _timer.Tick += OnTick;
                }
                else
                {
                    _timer.Tick -= OnTick;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void OnTick(object? sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Text = (DateTime.Now - Time).ToString(/* Specify text format */);
    }
}

And assuming your view model has a collection of DateTime named "Times" as a readonly public property, a simple ListBox which takes that collection would be as follows:
<ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Times}"
         VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"
         VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel/>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:TimerTextBlock Time="{Binding}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>


This is a very nice way, ty!

As you correctly state in your question, you would run a timer that updates the properties every X seconds.
Updating a DateTime struct is pretty cheap and when using WPF with data bindings it renders only the items in view by default, increasing performance by a lot.
1.000 objects is no problem. It only starts getting noticable once you hit 1.000.000, at which point you need to reconsider your design.

So there is no "easy way" to naturally display the time diference without using a specific property?

Nope, you need to code that yourself.

Okay. Is there a way to get the information that the listview is displayed? For exemple with a boolean binding IsDisplayed and when this boolean is true, the time is enabled too.

Yes, you can bind the Visibility property on your TextBlock and add a property in your Information class that returns System.Windows.Visibility.

The visibility will be false if I scroll and the object's line is not displayed?
